# ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() throws IOException on Android Versions below 3.0 (API11)

Tags: android, fileinputstream

The following Code seems to work fine on API Levels 11 and above:

```
   private ZipInputStream getFileFromZip(InputStream zipFileStream) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
     ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(zipFileStream);
     ZipEntry ze = null;
     while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
       Log.w(ACTIVITY_LOG_TAG, "extracting file: '" + ze.getName() + "'...");
       return zis;
     }
     return null;
    }
```

But throws an `IOException`when running under, e.g. 10 or 8. I want to support those APIs as well in my app, so I need to bring this to work...

I checked all the filenames, paths etc. And again, under 3.0 it works.
I also am using actionbarsherlock, although that should not impact the zip Input stream.

Does anyone have any ideas???

#### Update

I forgot to mention I'm doing this using `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`.

LogCat as requested by Blackbelt:

```
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Unable to extract databases/RGBColortype.zip to data directory
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:36)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:574)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:198)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:212)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.coloruapp.MainActivity.getFileFromZip(MainActivity.java:346)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.coloruapp.MainActivity.copyDatabaseFromAssets(MainActivity.java:321)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.coloruapp.MainActivity.access$2(MainActivity.java:315)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.coloruapp.MainActivity$DBInstaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:294)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.coloruapp.MainActivity$DBInstaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-08 11:12:17.478: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  ... 4 more
```

And afterwards, I obviously leak the `ProgressDialog`...

```
06-08 11:12:19.058: D/ActionBarSherlock(405): [dispatchStop]
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405): Activity com.coloruapp.MainActivity has       leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46090078 that was originally added here
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.coloruapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46090078 that was originally added here
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>   (ViewRoot.java:247)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at  android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at     com.coloruapp.MainActivity$DBInstaller.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:310)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at com.coloruapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:92)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-08 11:12:19.138: E/WindowManager(405):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the complete logcat? The snippet you provide should run indifferently on all the android version

Comment: Added the Error Output

Comment: in which way is it related to your problem?

Comment: The first logcat (about halfway down) shows the SQLiteException I am throwing. I happens when the ZipInputStream gets a IOException when unzipping the DB. This does not happen on all API levels from 11 up. It fails consistently for API levels 10 and lower.